# how to start bat string as a command

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, command, line

I have a good code which work
but I need to change it:

```
@echo off

java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar %_hostname%
```

I need to start this script with string and take a result like in privies Code,
I tried a different variant but only see this  `java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar %_hostname%` in my CMD line(((

```
@echo off

set /P "_temp_string=java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar %_hostname%"

cmd _temp_string
```

Comment: What do you want with the `set/p`? You can't edit a predefined text with it, you only enter new text. You should output the content of _temp_string to see what happens, with `echo %_temp_string%`

Comment: I had tried a different versions of using _temp_string, like: echo %_temp_string%  or %_temp_string% and other many variants, but i can't to find well one.

Comment: Try echoing the command string into a file with `echo ... > file.cmd` and then executing the file with `call file.cmd`

Comment: @MarkSetchell you are totally right,  ' echo java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar %_hostname% %_port% %_warning% %_critical% > file.cmd ' and [call file.cmd] work. But how i can do this throw the variable

Answer (score 0):

To start a command that is stored in a variable can be done via

```
%myCommand%
```

In your context you could try

```
@echo off
set /P "myCommand=Enter a complete command: "
echo You entered %myCommand%
%myCommand%
```

But perhaps you only want to add user defined parameters

```
@echo off
set /P "myPrams=Enter additional parameters: "
java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar %_hostname% %myParams%
```

Comment: Dell Foglight will sent parameters in this *.bat file, when starts it. So I only need to crate a variable after command java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar

Comment: What is `Dell Foglight`? How it _sends_ parameter to a batch file? What do you mean with `create a variable after command`? Please clarify your question, as it's not understandable. You could read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dell Foglight is monitoring system. It sent variables in %_hostname% , so when I start a first example, everything  work perfect. But now I want to write a lot of variables, so I need to use string, because I will change variables.

Comment: Allowing the user to type in any command and run it is a massively huge security risk. The user might type something like `DEL /S /Q C:\Windo...`